# two function at same time

Tags: android, multithreading, android-espresso

Is this possible to call two function at same time in Android Espresso tests.

I have two functions 
performDragNDrop (s, d) 
takeScreenshot()

I want to capture screen while dragNDrop in progress.

Comment: Why not call `takeScreenshot()` with delay using `new Handler().postDelayed();`?

Comment: So why not calling `takeScreenshot` inside `performDragNDrop`?

Comment: Thanks, can you give some detail example , sorry I am not Android developer, just doing a research task (not class assignment :) ). 

I am using fastlane screengrab to capture screen.
and dragdrop function is like 
myObject.performDragNDrop(direction.STEP_UP);